# show individual elements independently using each method

Tags: jquery, hover, each, fadein, fadeout

trying to show only one element at a time using each function, but not sure how to get matching item associated with first item so as you hover over first "hoverMe" it shows only first showMe and so on

here is what I have so far, I think I can do this a really messy way, but not sure if there is a clean way to do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pm2vP/

```
<p class="hoverMe">Hover me<span class="showMe">show me</span></p>
<p class="hoverMe">Hover me<span class="showMe">show me</span></p>
<p class="hoverMe">Hover me<span class="showMe">show me</span></p>

$('.showMe').hide();

$(".hoverMe").each(function(){
  $(this).hover(
    function () {
      $(".showMe").fadeIn();
    },
    function () {
      $(".showMe").fadeOut();
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` keyword will reference the currently hovered element inside the function, and using it as context in the selector, you can select only the spans inside the currently hovered paragraph.

`.hover()` is a shortcut for `.on('mouseenter mouseleave'`, and I find it easier just using that directly, and `fadeToggle()` will toggle the fading effect.

```
$('.showMe').hide();

$(".hoverMe").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
      $(".showMe", this).fadeToggle();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pm2vP/2/)

EDIT:

To make sure the fading toggle's correctly (which rarely is a problem), you can create your own toggle functionality:

```
$('.showMe').hide();

$(".hoverMe").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
      $(".showMe", this)[e.type=='mouseenter'?'fadeIn':'fadeOut']();
});
```

Comment: ah, I think I like this the best. It's very clean. I am reading up the .on method and fadeToggle, was unaware of these. thank you.

Comment: One thing I would be cautious about with this approach is the fade ever getting out of sync with the mouseenter/mouseleave state. It's feasible that given the right circumstances you could accidentally cause it to become visible on mouseleave and invisible on mouseenter. Just be wary.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.showMe').hide();

$('.hoverMe').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
    // looks within the hovered-over element:
    $(this)
        // to find the '.showMe' element
        .find('.showMe')
        // stops all currently-running animations
        .stop(true, true)
        // fades the discovered '.showMe' element(s) in, or out
        // depending on whether the mouse entered, or left, the '.hoverMe' element            
        .fadeToggle(e.type == 'mouseenter');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Pm2vP/4/).

This does, though, use jQuery 1.9 (unlike your original demo, which used 1.6.4).

If, however, you want to stay wtih jQuery 1.6.4, you can use `delegate()`, though it's a little uglier, unfortunately:

```
$('.showMe').hide();

$('.hoverMe').parent().delegate('.hoverMe', 'mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
    $(this).find('.showMe').stop(true, true).fadeToggle(e.type == 'mouseenter');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Pm2vP/5/).

References:

- [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).
- [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

Comment: I'm not stuck with 1.6, it's just what the project currently is using. Definitely able to upgrade. Would prefer cleaner syntax. I will try this now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.showMe').hide();
$(".hoverMe").mouseover(function(){
$('.showMe').fadeOut();
$(this).find(".showMe").fadeIn();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For each item with class `hoverMe`, this code finds the children of the hovered item with the `showMe` class and makes them `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`.

```
$(".hoverMe").each(function(){
  $(this).hover(
    function () {
      $(this).children(".showMe").fadeIn();
    },
    function () {
      $(this).children(".showMe").fadeOut();
    }
  );
});
```