# jQuery hidden div using hover showing all hidden divs

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

I'm sure it's been asked, but I couldn't find a solution to my issue. I have a class that is named the same across 3 divs. This class is being hidden using css. The issue is that when I hover over 1 of the divs, all 3 show the hidden at the same time. I just want the element that I am hovered on to show. I think I should use .each() but I'm not sure how it all fits together.

CSS

```
.background-hover {
    display: none;
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="home-get-started">
   <-- first--><div class="home-get-started">
            <!-- image-->
            <img src="image.png">
              <!-- hover hidden state -->               
                <div class="background-hover">
                <div class="home-btn">Text</div>
                </div>
            </div>

<--second --> <div class="home-get-started">
            <!-- image-->
            <img src="image.png">
              <!-- hover hidden state -->               
                <div class="background-hover">
                <div class="home-btn">Text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".home-get-started").hover(
function () { $('.background-hover').css({"display":"block"}); },
function () { $('.background-hover').css({"display":"none"}); }
);
```

Comment: A possible duplicate of [show individual elements independently using each method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471954/show-individual-elements-independently-using-each-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are showing/hiding all elements with class `background-hover`. What you probably want is to do this only to descendants of the element which triggered the event...

You can use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to query the DOM for the descendants of a certain element (`this` in our case).

```
$(".home-get-started").hover(
    function () { $(this).find('.background-hover').show(); },
    function () { $(this).find('.background-hover').hide(); }
);
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SsVp7/)

Be aware the in some cases both Texts will show at the same time - that's because your wrapper div also has the home-get-started class so the hover handlers will fire for that element too.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was something as easy as that. I was just stumped.

Answer (score 1):

How about this. you can use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jVzR6/)

```
$(".home-get-started").hover(
    function () { $(this).find('.background-hover').toggle(); }

);
```

Also you have an extra `<div class="home-get-started">` is that intended. If so hovering over that will trigger all of them.

If that is how it is then best bet is to use immediate child selector `>` to avoid opening of both.

```
$(".home-get-started").hover(
   function () {
       $('> .background-hover', this).toggle();
   }
);
```